# What should be the workflow for <cfoauth> tag in ColdFusion 11?

Tags: facebook, oauth, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Today I was looking into the `<cfoauth>` tag of ColdFusion 11.
Steps I followed:

1. I have created one app on Facebook using my local site url (http://cf11local.com/).
2. I got the client id and the secret key.
3. In Login.cfm I have used:

   `<cfoauth type="facebook" 
       clientid="***" 
       secretkey="************" 
       result="res" 
       redirecturi="http://cf11local.com/login.cfm" 
       scope=email>`
4. I have successfully retrieved all my Facebook info in a structure format.

Now my question is:

- How will I check in each page that the particular user is logged in using Facebook or not?
- How will I implement the logout functionality by this?

Answer (score 2):

To integrate facebook functionality into your site, you need to follow steps mentioned bellow:

1. Provide 'Login Via Facebook' option
2. Once the user clicks the Facebook login button, user will be asked to login to facebook if the user is not already logged in. If the user is already logged in, the user will be prompted with a popup to grant permissions to access information.
3. Once the user give permission or if the user already authorized your app, the user will be immediately redirected to your redirect url that you specified in oauth tag's redirecturi attribute along with the login info in a variable mentioned in oauth tag's result attribute. The result attribute will be a struct. 
    **(You have achieved this till now. Thanks for being patient.)
   Now to answer your question.**
4. You need to keep this result variable into the session scope so that it can be accesed in the same session in other pages. You can do this using `<cfset Session.fbinfo = #res#>`
5. After this redirect the user to the desired page by using cflocation tag. 
   `<cflocation url = "desired page">`
6. On every page, check whether the user's login info is in the session scope or not. If the session does not have the login information, redirect him to login page.
   `<cfif (not isdefined('Session.fbinfo'))>
   <cflocation url = "login page">
   </cfif>`
    If session has login info, well the user is free to access site.
7. Once the user logs out, you need to invalide the access token present in the session. You can do that using `InvalidateOauthAccesstoken("access token", "facebook")`
8. Clear the user information from the session. 
   `<cfset StructClear(Session)>`